# Copy specific cells after certain period

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file name Sample.xlsm

I need to copy data updated on specific cells on  i.e. Sheet3 C13, D13, E13

to Sheet4 B1, C1, D1

Data need to updated every 5 min & it should be pasted on the next row i.e. B2:C2, B3:C3.

[image]

it is giving me runtime error.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Instead, include the code itself.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the line with the breakpoint is throwing the error, the returned cell is likely the last cell in column B (B1048576) and you are performing an offset of one row which is out of range of the cells.  Instead try something like:

```
Range("B2:B" & Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

This should get you on the right path but it is hard to know without seeing your data or code.